# AsyncCallback pass parameter

Tags: c#, asynccallback

I want to pass `List<items>` into `AsyncCallback` in function `LoadHistoryAsync(List<int> Items)` but `result.AsyncState` in `CallForNewData(IAsyncResult result)` is null why?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> Items = new List<int>();
        Data D = new Data();
        D.LoadHistoryAsync(Items);
        //D.LoadNewPointsAsync(Items);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public void LoadHistoryAsync(List<int> Items)
    {
        Action<List<int>> GetHistoryInformation = new Action<List<int>>(GetHistory);
        //IAsyncResult History = GetHistoryInformation.BeginInvoke(Items, null, null);
        IAsyncResult History = GetHistoryInformation.BeginInvoke(Items, new AsyncCallback(CallForNewData), null);
    }

    public void GetHistory(List<int> Items)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1,5000));
        Items.Add(1);
        Console.WriteLine("HistoryLoaded");
    }
    public void CallForNewData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",result.AsyncState);
    }

    public void LoadNewPointsAsync(List<int> Items)
    {
        //while(!History.IsCompleted)
        //{
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        //}
        Action<List<int>> GetPointsInformation = new Action<List<int>>(GetPoints);
        IAsyncResult NewPoints = GetPointsInformation.BeginInvoke(Items, null, null);
    }

    public void GetPoints(List<int> Items)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1, 5000));
        Items.Add(2);
        Console.WriteLine("New data loaded");
    }
}
}
```

Edit:

```
IAsyncResult History = GetHistoryInformation.BeginInvoke(Items, new AsyncCallback(CallForNewData), Items);
```

Solved problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The **BeginInvoke** method initiates the asynchronous call. It has the same parameters as the method that you want to execute asynchronously, plus two additional optional parameters. The first parameter is an *AsyncCallback* delegate that references a method to be called when the asynchronous call completes. ***The second parameter is a user-defined object that passes information into the callback method***.

You pass a `null`, you get a `null`.